# Special characters replace using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

Just for learning I am trying to replace all the special characters present in the keyboard to replace with `underscore'_'`

```
List of characters= ~!@#$%^&*()+|}{:"?><-=[]\;',./
```

`string I created:`

```
table = """123~!@#$%^&*()+|}{:"?><-=[]\;',./"""

import re

table1= re.sub(r'!~@#$%^&*()-+={}[]:;<.>?/\'"', '_', table)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/re.py", line 151, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/re.py", line 242, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: unexpected end of regular expression
```

Unable to do so I am getting the above error.

How can I replace the special characters in the string using regex

Comment: Is that your exact string? It does not have any quotes. Try `table = """..."""` Also, what's with the `123` at the beginning?

Comment: Note that `)-+` creates an *invalid* range. Always put the `-` at the end/start of the character class. Yeah, and use a character class :)

Comment: @tobias_k yes it is the exact string and nothing in front of `123`

Comment: @tobias_k I have tried with `table = """123~!@#$%^&*()+|}{:"?><-=[]\;',./"""
` but still same error

Comment: @New_learner: Have you read Wiktor's comment as well?

Comment: See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/A4DP8o).

Comment: There's also `\W`, which matches-all non-word characters: `re.sub(r'\W', '_', some_string)`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

Comment: @Blurp Good point, but that would also replace e.g. whitespace. Might use something like `[^\w\s]` though, depending on what exactly OP wants to replace. Also, there seem to be chars like `|` what shall not be replaced (might be a mistake in the question, though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `re.escape` to escape all the special regex characters in the string, and then enclose the escaped string into `[...]` so it matches any of them.

```
>>> re.sub("[%s]" % re.escape('!~@#$%^&*()-+={}[]:;<.>?/\''), '_', table)
'123____________|___"_______\\__,__'
```

However, as you are not really using that regex as a regex, you might instead just check whether each character is in that string:

```
>>>''.join("_" if c in '!~@#$%^&*()-+={}[]:;<.>?/\'' else c for c in table)
'123____________|___"_______\\__,__'
```

Or to make the lookup a bit faster, create a `set` from the chars in that string first:

```
>>> bad_chars = set('!~@#$%^&*()-+={}[]:;<.>?/\'')
>>> ''.join("_" if c in bad_chars else c for c in table)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put it in a character class and rearrange the position of some characters (namely `-`, escaping `+`):

```
import re
table = """123~!@#$%^&*()+|}{:"?><-=[]\;',./"""

table1 = re.sub(r'[-\+!~@#$%^&*()={}\[\]:;<.>?/\'"]', '_', table)
print(table1)
# 123____________|___________\__,__
```